# HttpUrlConnection doesn't seem so release connection to server

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpUrlConnection for making network calls. I used `urlconnection.disconnect()` and `inputstream.close()` for closing connection

```
    try {
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) getUrlConnection(new URL(mUrl));
                uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                uc.setDoOutput(true);
                uc.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
    in.close();
    } catch (...) {
    ........
    } finally {
        if(uc != null)
            uc.disconnect();
    }
```

After I run `netstat` command on server. But still I saw one tcp connection in open state.
Is there any to close HttpUrlConnection

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/   http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

Answer (score 1):

The [disconnect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()) method states:

> Releases this connection so that its resources may be either reused or
>   closed.
>
> Unlike other Java implementations, this will not necessarily close
>   socket connections that can be reused. You can disable all connection
>   reuse by setting the http.keepAlive system property to false before
>   issuing any HTTP requests.

Comment: setting http.keepAlive doesn't work seems like it reuses the connection for other calls. I tried setting "connection" to close. `uc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");` now connections are getting closed in 5 sec. but that floods new connections as I am making network calls very frequently.

Comment: I want to restrict number of open connection to specific server

Comment: What if you don't call `uc.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(0);`

Comment: I am not calling `uc.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(0)` also don't think that will work since I have set default length to 0

Comment: Sorry, meant uc.setChunkedStreamingMode(0)

Comment: refer this [link](https://mttkay.github.io/blog/2013/03/02/herding-http-requests-or-why-your-keep-alive-connection-may-be-dead/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like android always uses different port for opening every new connection. and caches them for some time.
refer [this link](https://mttkay.github.io/blog/2013/03/02/herding-http-requests-or-why-your-keep-alive-connection-may-be-dead/)